# Testing .pipe in Angular Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs

I would like to test the following .ts file:

```
create(entityResourceID, params: any): Observable <any>{
  const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${entityResourceID}/assignee`;
  return this.http.post(url, params).pipe(
    map(() => { this.toaster.success('Successfully Asssigned Email'); }),
    catchError((error) => [
      console.error(error),
      this.toaster.error('Failed Assigning Email')
    ])
  );
}
```

however I am currently getting the error `.pipe is not a function`

here is my test spec.ts file currently:

```
describe('create', () => {
    it('should return a valid url', () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(mockHttpClient, 'post').mockReturnValue('test');
        const result = component.create(testEntityID, {});
        expect(spy).toBeCalledWith('entities/url/assignee', {});
        expect(result).toStrictEqual('test');
    });
});
```

I understand that is made difficult because I am returning a type Observable. I need to return an Observable from my spy so I can test both of my cases, but how exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because you mock the **post** method and return a string value instead of an Observable with your value inside. I dont know if you are using rxjs, but you can do something like this..

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const spy = jest.spyOn(mockHttpClient,'post').mockReturnValue(of('test'));
```

**of** method is a short way of *Obeservable.of(yourValueHere)*